# Module Import Error Img

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to import the image module from pillow 5.1.0. Using python 3.6.5.

I typed in the following command

```
from PIL import image.
```

Upon doing this I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import image
ImportError: cannot import name 'image'
```

Comment: it's `Image` with a capital `I` and not `image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `from PIL import Image` (note the capital 'I' in Image).